# TableView load issue in ios simulator 64-bit

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, ios-simulator, 32bit-64bit

I have an application with a `UITableView` that works perfectly on `iPhone Simulator 3.5-inch and 4 inch` but doesn't load table in the `64-bit Simulator`. May be it's just that something is wrong with my `xib` file or code, but I just wanted to know if there are any changes in `UITableView` delegates in the 64-bit `iOS`.

Comment: what is the error while running

Comment: There is no error, it doesn't load the data

Comment: Do you have a .nib file for the tableview? Sometimes the simulator leaves behind old files, typically .nib & .strings files. In your case you could be loading an old .nib file where the tableview property is not set.

Solution; use "reset content & settings" in the simulator. Please let me know if this works.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the same Problem. In my case the problem could be solved by changing

```
- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

As simple as that.

Comment: Thanks, I just resolved it 5 minutes before your answer by the same way you mentioned.

Comment: This fixed a lot of strange UI issues with several of my tableviews. Much appreciated.

Comment: wow. life saver! There is also a warning about it that I was ignoring.

Comment: The problem is, my other table views are working perfectly fine on 64-bit simulator while using `- (float)` ... only one table had this issue. Ideally it either should work for all, or shouldn't work for any `UITableView`

Comment: Anyone still having this issue doesn't show the table view on an iPhone 4s in the simulator